# Can't switch to TTY on Ubuntu 17.10 fresh installation, Keys work fine, chvt works

Tags: tty

This seems weird.

When I press Ctrl-Alt-F[1-6], nothing happens.

The keys are registered correctly

`xev` output

> KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
>       root 0x1e3, subw 0x0, time 955536, (141,111), root:(341,321),
>       state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
>       root 0x1e3, subw 0x0, time 956147, (141,111), root:(341,321),
>       state 0x4, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> MappingNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
>       request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248
>
> KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
>       root 0x1e3, subw 0x0, time 957484, (141,111), root:(341,321),
>       state 0xc, keycode 67 (keysym 0x1008fe01, XF86Switch_VT_1), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False

`chvt 1` gives me

> Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console

`sudo chvt 1` and `sudo chvt 2` bring me to the x window login screen.

`sudo chvt 3` brings me to the text console login.

What should I do to enable the `Ctrl-Alt-F*` to bring me to the text console?

Comment: Some modern laptops have the `F1-F12` keys locked to the Volume, Brightness, Touchpad etc. In such case one has to press e.g. `Ctrl+Alt+Fn+F2`. Isn't that the case?